# Generating SQL Query

Tags: mysql

have the following DB structure in MySQL:

Table1: ORDER
With Attributes

- ID (PRIMARY KEY)
- DELIVERY_DATE
- CUSTOMER_ID
- RESTAURANT_ID
- ORDER_VALUE

Table2 : CUSTOMER
With Attributes

- ID (PRIMARY KEY)
- NAME
- LOGIN

Table 3: Restaurant

- ID (PRIMARY KEY)
- NAME
- CITY

I want to generate a db query where I select the customer_ID, login, Delivery_date, Sequence number, And the number of days from the last order to the second to last order.

I am having trouble using Inner join and generating the last two columns of my query:

- Sequence: Each user may have ordered any number of dishes, I want to show a number three if it is the third time he orders, I should be able to get it from his customer_ID and the Order_ID
- DateDiff from last order: I am having trouble getting the last and the second to last order and doing a dateDIFF and populating the column

I have so far constructed the following query:

```
SELECT customer_id,
       login,
       delivery_date,
       sequence,
       Datediff(second_to_last_order, last_order)
FROM   order AS t1
       INNER JOIN customer AS t2
               ON t1.customer_id = t2.id
       INNER JOIN restaurant AS t3
               ON t1.restaurant_id = t3.id;
```

But it is obviously incomplete but i am stuck, any suggestions?

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ? Also, please provide **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308

Comment: The reason I have asked the MySQL server version because it *looks* like a `LEAD/LAG` Window functions problem. These have been made available in MySQL 8+ onwards. So, if you can upgrade to the latest version, that would be great indeed!

Answer (score 0):

If this is MySQL Server query as you mentioned then I'd suggest you give the following a go;

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, LOGIN, DELIVERY_DATE, SEQUENCE, DATEDIFF((SELECT MAX(z.ORDER_DATE) FROM ORDER AS z WHERE z.CUSTOMER_ID = t1.CUSTOMER_ID), (SELECT MAX(x.ORDER_DATE) FROM ORDER AS x WHERE x.CUSTOMER_ID = t1.CUSTOMER_ID AND x.ID != (SELECT MAX(x.ID) FROM ORDER AS x2 WHERE x2.CUSTOMER_ID = t1.CUSTOMER_ID)))
FROM ORDER AS a
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER AS t2 ON t1.CUSTOMER_ID = t2.ID
INNER JOIN RESTAURANT AS t3 ON t1.RESTAURANT_ID = t3.ID
ORDER BY t1;
```

I would advice that it's good practise to not call a table "ORDER" as this is a keyword used by MySQL, you could instead simple call the table "ORDERS" to avoid the issue.

This should do what you are asking for, if you have any issue please post any error text so we can better understand what you are facing.

Comment: ORDER is a reserved word in MySQL